# Compare two lists to find identical values, return the missing value

Tags: python, loops

My program is to iterate through coordinates(list) and check to see if 3 coordinates come out True from the ocoords(list) and return or possibly get that False value(coordinate)

I'm trying to find an efficient way of finding similar values in two lists that are structured differently but have the same coordinates.

```
coordinates = [[(2,2),(3,2)],[(2,2),(2,3)],[(4,2),(5,2)],[(5,2),(6,2)]]


#iterating through coordinates...
>>>
[(2, 2), (3, 2)]
[(2, 2), (2 ,3)]
[(4, 2), (5, 2)]
[(5, 2), (6, 2)]
```

Then my next list is structured like this (with specified coordinates that should go together...

```
ocoords = [[[(2,2),(3,2)],[(2,2),(2,3)],[(4,2),(5,2)],[(3,3),(3,2)]], <-- last value is not identical
 [[(3,2),(4,2)],[(3,2),(3,3)],[(3,3),(4,3)],[(4,3),(4,2)]]] <-- structure of list
```

So how would you go about this? I'm novice to this, so sorry for the question. I thought of using Boolean, but then I need to get that value that is False.

I want to see if any of the coordinates are in ocoords [0] and if they are, but one isn't give me that value.

Comment: It isn't very clear what the returned value would be. And the description of `ocoords`' structure is also not clear.

Comment: I want to see if any of the coordinates are in ocoords [0] and if they are, but one isn't give me that value.

Comment: You should add that as part of the question. BTW, Is the order of the items always aligned as in your example or it could be arbitrary?

Comment: That's a good question , does it matter if they are random or not? That's why I wanted to iterate through them.

Comment: You could easily `zip` the items and compare pair-wise until the condition fails if the items were aligned. If they are not, it will be a different approach altogether.

Comment: Thank you I will give this a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) with a *predicate* that checks for items in `coordinates` that are also contained in `ocoords[0]`:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

val = next(dropwhile(lambda x: x in ocoords[0], coordinates))
print(val)
# [(5, 2), (6, 2)]
```

If the items are aligned, you can go faster with `zip` and not having to check for the containment of each item, rather check until there is a pair-wise mismatch:

```
val = next(dropwhile(lambda x: x[0]==x[1], zip(coordinates, ocoords[0])))
print(val[0])  
# [(5, 2), (6, 2)]
```